# Включение авто-дополнения в Sublime Text по сочетанию клавиш

Tags: sublime-text-3, autocomplete

Как включить/выключить авто-дополнение (auto_complete) в Sublime Text по сочетанию клавиш?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

С помощью вот такого куска кода мне удалось выполнить задачу (добавить в файл key bindings)

```
{"keys": ["ctrl+alt+x"], "command": "set_setting", "args": {"setting": "auto_complete", "value": false }, "context":
    [
        {"key": "setting.auto_complete", "operator": "equal", "operand": true}
    ]
},
{"keys": ["ctrl+alt+x"], "command": "set_setting", "args": {"setting": "auto_complete", "value": true }, "context":
    [
        {"key": "setting.auto_complete", "operator": "equal", "operand": false}
    ]
},
```